# Create a simple PyTorch neural network with a normalized weights

Tags: neural-network, pytorch

I want to create a simple PyTorch neural network with the sum of its weights equal to `1`. To understand my question here is a to give an example:

[image]

Comment: `torch.nn.utils.weight_norm()` might be what you're looking for: https://pytorch.org/docs/1.9.0/generated/torch.nn.utils.weight_norm.html#torch.nn.utils.weight_norm

Comment: to use your method do i have to write? from torch.nn.utils import weight_norm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply normalize by the sum of all initialized weights:

```
>>> layer = nn.Linear(4, 1, bias=False)
>>> layer.weight
Parameter containing:
tensor([[-0.2565,  0.4753, -0.1129,  0.2327]], requires_grad=True)
```

Normalize `layer.weight`:

```
>>> layer.weight.data /= layer.weight.data.sum()
```

Then:

```
>>> layer.weight
Parameter containing:
tensor([[-0.7573,  1.4034, -0.3333,  0.6872]], requires_grad=True)
```

Comment: can you give me the full code for this example? and thank you

Comment: the complete code that implements or represents the figure above, I want to figure things out from this simple example so that I can make a more complex network.

Comment: Well, `layer` is your neuron receiving four inputs and the sum of its weights is one. I don't quite see what you would like to know more.